# Compute differences between 2 HTML pages and dynamically change first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HMTL page that is (re-)generated every 3 seconds and I need to expose these changes to users.

Since I can't change the generator to write in a different format (json) and read using AJAX, right now we just have a javascript that refreshes the whole page every 10 seconds.

Ideally, what I need instead of refreshing the whole page, is to refresh only the fields that changed.

The page structure never changes, only value of table cells. Every table cell has a different class name.

Ex:

Original HTML, running at user's browser contains:

```
<html><body><div class="firstDiv">1000</div></body></html>
```

After 3 seconds it changes in the server to:

```
<html><body><div class="firstDiv">2000</div></body></html>
```

A javascript would read via AJAX the changed HTML every 3 seconds, calculate the difference and apply only what changed to the page already opened at user's browser, using javascript:

```
$('.firstDiv').html('2000');
```

So my question is: Is there any tool/library that can help me with this task?

Comment: I would use a databinding library like knockout. It is built specifically for this purpose. See: http://knockoutjs.com/

An example would be: 
`<html><body><div class="firstDiv" data-bind="text: someNumberFromAjax"></div></body</html>`

Comment: @PierreTasci to replace the content I used jQuery but could be anything. My main question is how to compare 2 HTML and get a list of which elements changed content and what is the new content so it can be replaced in the current HTML.

Comment: Can describe "calculate the difference and apply only what changed to the open page at user's browser" ? e.g., 2000-1000 ?

Comment: Why are you trying to only update the DOM that has changed? For efficiency/speed reasons? Or because you want to be able to highlight the changes?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. So the user loads the page in the browser, it has a div with contents "1000". In this page there's a javascript running checking for changes in the server (via ajax to the same html), if there's a change (new div content is "2000"), then only the div that changed is updated dynamically. Hope is more clear now..

Comment: @GregL Yes, it is to avoid reloading the whole page, so it is for efficiency and speed (which translates in user experience). Highlighting would be a plus, which should be easy if there's an algorithm that detects which div changed.

Comment: How big is this page? If it is anything beyond small, that is a _lot_ of work for the client to be doing. Because the client would have to be continuously fetching the page from the server, calculating the diff, and applying it, goto 10. Ugh. Can you introduce another server to do this for you and push updates to the browser via Websockets / Server Sent Events? NodeJS would be great for this.

Comment: @GregL Yes, that's a good point. The page is a spreadsheet so it's large. What you described is definitely ideal but we are working on an MVP (minimum viable product) to demo to possible investors so I guess it's ok to overload the client with some extra processing in this case.

Comment: @GregL About the websockets solution, I guess the problem about calculating the changes between 2 HTMLs is still there, just done in the server side and published to the user via sockets. I would be happy to implement that if I could calculate those differences.

Comment: Again, the right solution here is databinding. You set up a knockout observable. You query every x seconds via ajax and replace the value of that observable. Knockout will take care of efficiently updating the DOM to match. Or if you have an array of data, use knockout arrays. You can store all your data in there, then update all of it every 30s. It will take care of efficiently updating the UI based on what has actually changed.